# Please Help Me with Questions in Evans' PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have stuck by the following two problems in Evans' PDE books (2nd edition), 
The  problems require me to provide two counterexamples.
problem 1: (see Page 307 Problem 12 )
U is open and $V \subset \subset U$,Show by example that if we have $||D^{h}u||_{L^1(V)} \leq C$ for all $0<h<\frac{1}{2}dist(V,\partial U)$, it does not necessarily follow that $u \in W^{1,1}(V)$.
problem 2:(see page 307 Problem 13)
Give an example of an open set $U\subset R^n$ and a function $u \in W^{1,\infty}(U)$,
such that $u$ is not Lipschitz continuous on $U$.

I hope someone will kindly give an answer this time. Thank you very much.